# Iterator deveria retornar uma String

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, machine-learning

Olá, eu estou com o seguinte código:

```
import csv

def carregar_acessos():

    X = []
    Y = []

    arquivo = open('acesso_pagina.csv', 'rb')
    leitor = csv.reader(arquivo)
    next(leitor)


    for home,como_funciona,contato,comprou in leitor:

        dado = [int(home),int(como_funciona),int(contato)]
        X.append(dado)
        Y.append([int(comprou)])
```

Ele tenta retirar informações de um arquivo CSV contendo vários ZEROS e UNS. E tenho outro arquivo que mostra isto no terminal:

```
from dados import carregar_acessos

X,Y = carregar_acessos()

print(X)
print(Y)
```

Porém quando eu rodo o código o seguinte erro aparece:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifica_acesso.py", line 3, in <module>
    X,Y = carregar_acessos()
  File "/Users/josecarlosferreira/Desktop/machine-learning/dados.py", line 10, in carregar_acessos
    next(leitor)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Bem, vi algumas respostas no Stackoverflow em Inglês, porém mesmo tentando as soluções lá propostas o código não funcionava e continuava mantendo o mesmo erro.

O CSV está criado desta forma:

```
home,como_funciona,contato,comprou
1,1,0,0
1,1,0,0
1,1,0,0
1,1,0,0
1,1,0,0
1,0,1,1
1,1,0,0
1,0,1,1
1,1,0,0
1,0,1,1
```

E segue assim por mais 200 linhas. Elas indicam cada uma uma informação de SIM(1) e NÃO(0).
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Como é a estrutura do teu csv?

Comment: Editei o tópico para demonstrar!

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

def carregar_acessos():
    X = []
    Y = []

    arquivo = open('acesso.csv', 'rb')
    leitor = csv.reader(arquivo)

    next(leitor)

    for home,como_funciona,contato, comprou in leitor:

        dado = [int(home),int(como_funciona)
            ,int(contato)]
        X.append(dado)
        Y.append(int(comprou))

    return X, Y
```

Comment: Caraca como eu deixei passar o Return kkkk As vezes as coisas estão na nossa cara e estamos caçando algo mais complexo e esquecemos do Básico! Obrigado Marcelo.

Comment: ainda bem que era um return

Comment: Eu achei que tinha resolvido. Eu fui tentar rodar e não funcionou! Continua dando o mesmo erro!

Answer (score 0):

Com a função [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) do `pandas` fica mais simples essa leitura da sua tabela, no arquivo `dados.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

def carregar_acessos():
    
    arquivo = pd.read_csv('acesso_pagina.csv')
    return arquivo
```

e no arquivo principal:

```
from dados import carregar_acessos

df = carregar_acessos()
print(df)
```

finalmente, a saída será:

```
   home  como_funciona  contato  comprou
0     1              1        0        0
1     1              1        0        0
2     1              1        0        0
3     1              1        0        0
4     1              1        0        0
5     1              0        1        1
6     1              1        0        0
7     1              0        1        1
8     1              1        0        0
9     1              0        1        1
```